# compilation error when changing variable from char to String

Tags: compilation-errors, avr-gcc

I have a code with these two lines:

```
  char handshakecode = "S"; // Capital S
  char receive;
```

The lines of code are placed in a separate `void`, and not `setup` or `loop`.
When i change the two variables from `char` to `String` i get a error(complete error at bottom) when compiling to the arduino or verifying the code.

```
  String handshakecode = "S"; // Capital S
  String receive;
```

When i snippes out partial code for just that particular `void`, it compiles fine, so it must be in combination with the rest of the code, which i have left out from this post at the moment.

Is this a known error or am I doing something wrong?

> In function 'global constructors keyed to 65535_0_WFS_v0.3.ino.cpp.o':
>
> lto1.exe: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
>
> Please submit a full bug report,
>
> with preprocessed source if appropriate.
>
> See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html for instructions.
>
> lto-wrapper.exe: fatal error: C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc
>   returned 1 exit status
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> c:/program
>   files/windowsapps/arduinollc.arduinoide_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe:
>   error: lto-wrapper failed
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> exit status 1 Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega
>   2560.

Comment: that does not look like a compilation error ... that looks like a compiler program failure .... try reinstalling the Arduino IDE

Comment: This is a known error with the windows store version of the IDE. Delete it and download it from Arduino.

Comment: @Majenko it happens with the regular version of the Arduino IDE also.

Comment: Interesting. It used to just be the app version. I guess they messed up the real version. Another reason to switch to [UECIDE](https://uecide.org) I guess :)

Comment: I encountered the bug using the standard Arduino IDE back when the new toolchain was still in beta testing, as well as with the production release. I'm normally all about using the latest versions of everything but I'm stuck with Arduino AVR Boards 1.6.21 until this gets fixed.

Comment: I just did a review of all occurrences of the bug and 22 were using the Windows App version of the Arduino IDE, 17 were using the regular Arduino IDE, 3 did not show which version they were using. In all cases, the OS was Windows. So this is good evidence that it's completely unrelated to which IDE version is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is specific to the 5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2 version of avr-gcc used by Arduino AVR Boards 1.6.22 and newer. It has been reported here:

https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/7949

Here's the workaround:

1. Tools > Board > Boards Manager
2. Wait for downloads to finish.
3. When you move the mouse pointer over "Arduino AVR Boards", you will see a "Select version" dropdown menu appear. Select "1.6.21".
4. Click "Install".
5. Wait for installation to finish.
6. Click "Close".

Due to a [bug](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/7973), this workaround doesn't work with Arduino IDE 1.8.6, but it will work with any other version of the Arduino IDE.

If you have **File > Preferences > Check for updates on startup** checked, the Arduino IDE may occasionally notify you that a new version of Arduino AVR Boards is available, you'll need to refrain from updating back to the new Arduino AVR Boards version, otherwise you'll be back to seeing the segmentation fault error again.